# How can I cancel a download that's too big or slow in a lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios, fetch

I'm using axios in a lambda function to download a file from a user provided url. Obviously that file could be any size, and might be served at any speed. I am concerned that might create Denial of Service and Denial of Wallet risks.

I don't know if aws have any charges for lambda ingress, I haven't been able to find a definitive answer yet. Even if they don't though, large uploads could still force my lambdas to run for longer (costing me money) and potentially pushing me up against the rate limits I have set, in part, to mitigate flooding attack risk (denying people service).

Likewise, very slow downloads might cause my lambdas to run til they time out. My timeouts are set fairly high because there is processing to do once the file is downloaded. I'd rather bale after a small handful of seconds as the input data should always be small and fast.

So what I want is for downloads to abort if they hit a preset maximum size in bytes OR a maximum download time.

If adding these limits isn't possible with Axios then I'm open to using different libraries like node-fetch.

Comment: Was [Axios Cancellation](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation) not helpful? Also, be aware that you can retrieve the "time until Lambda timeout" from the Lambda context using `context.getRemainingTimeInMillis()`.

Comment: Also, yes AWS Lambda charges [data transfer fees](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/) into and out of your Lambda function except within region.

Comment: At the axios side itself, you can set a timeout and maxContentLength to limit the request time and download time. Lambda max timeout us 15minutes. If you possibly have many lengthy request, it is better to use EC2. Huge numbers of Lambda requests at high memory and high duration ends up more costly than EC2

Comment: @addicted - That's the right answer, many thanks. If you want to submit it as an actual answer I will happily accept it so you get credit.

Comment: Thanks @RogerHeathcote! Let me submit and much thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the axios side itself, you can set a timeout and maxContentLength to limit the request time and download time. Lambda max timeout us 15 minutes.

If you possibly have many lengthy request, it is better to use EC2. Huge numbers of Lambda requests at high memory and high duration ends up more costly than EC2. Basically Serverless is indeed cost-effective and easy operationally especially for spiky type of workload. For steady 24/7 workload, long processing-times, better use VM.